# Send information while pressing a submit button

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, button, contact-form-7

Heey,

I have a form that I need to validate that the fields are not empty and then when I press the submit button it will use a createAccount.php file to insert all the information the user introduce into the database. The problem is that when I press the submit button, nothing happen... I dont know what im doing worng. Any help will be very appreciated. Here is the code:

**HTML (in a contact form 7)**

```
<form id="myform" action="/wp-content/plugins/my-codes/createAccount.php" method="post">
<p>Your Name (required)<br /> </p>
[text* cName id:cName]

<p>Your Surname (required)<br /> </p>
[text* cSurname id:cSurname]

<p>Your Email (required)<br /></p>
[email* cEmail id:cEmail] 

<label> Your Telephone Number (required)
[tel* cPhone id:cPhone tel-106 placeholder "123 456 789"] </label>

<p>Your Address (required)<br /> </p>
[text* cAddress id:cAddress]

<select cNeighborhood id:cNeighborhood name=cNeighborhood>
<option value="Bat Yam">Bat Yam</option>
<option value="Raanana">Raanana</option>
</select>

<label> Create Password (required)
[text* cPswd id:cPswd] </label>

<label> Confirm Password (required)
[text* cPswd id:cPswd] </label>

[submit id:submit "submit"]
</form>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script     src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js">      </script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-           methods.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#myform").validate({
rules: {
    },
messages: {
   }
});
</script>
```

**createAccount.php**

```
<?php 
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
include ('../../../wp-config.php');
global $wpdb;    
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name=addslashes($_POST['cName']);
$surname=addslashes($_POST['cSurname']);
$email=addslashes($_POST['cEmail']);
$phone =addslashes($_POST['cPhone']);
$otherPhone=implode($_POST['cOtherPhone']);
$languages=implode(' | ', $_POST['cLanguages']);
$address=addslashes($_POST['cAddress']);
$neighborhood=$_POST['cNeighborhood'];
$pswd=addslashes($_POST['cPswd']);
$service=$_POST['cService'];                
$wpdb->insert("Client",array(
"cName"=>$name,
"cSurname"=>$surname,
"cEmail"=>$email,
"cPhone"=>$phone,
"cOtherPhone"=>$otherPhone,
"cLanguages"=>$languages,
"cAddress"=>$address,
"cNeighborhood"=>$neighborhood,
"cPswd"=>$pswd,
"cService"=>$service
));
print_r("uq");
}   

$wpdb->show_errors();
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: action="/wp-content/plugins/my-    codes/createAccount.php" method="post" //put this in form tag not in button

Comment: Make your `<form>` tag as, `<form id="myform"  action="/wp-content/plugins/my-    codes/createAccount.php" method="post">` and change your `submit` button code to `<input type="submit" name="submit">`

Comment: I tried that, actually that was my first approach. But notihng..

Comment: Openup the `devtools` in your chrome browser and goto the `console` and check if it reports any error.

Comment: Did it as well, no error messages

Comment: Did you check the `network` tab as well (to inspect the requests are going fine) ??

Comment: All good...GET 200 it say

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121633/discussion-between-david-r-and-alguienenestemundo).